# Calculate principal curvature of an hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I am having issues to calculate the principal curvatures and directions of a hypersurface.
I have the hypersurface defined as $S=f(\mathbf{x})$ with $\mathbf{x}\in R^n$, and I can compute all the first and second derivatives respect to $x_i$ (where $\mathbf{x} = [x_1,...,x_n]$).

I need to compute the principal curvatures and directions at a generic point $\mathbf{x}_0$.

From what I understood, I need to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the shape operator ( or Weingartner map ) but I still have problem to figure out how to obtaining the shape operator from the derivative respect to $x_i$.

I found several example when $\mathbf{x} \in R^2$ (therefore a surface $\in R^3$), but I have some difficulties to extend that notion in higher dimensions.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: When you say $S = f(\mathbf x)$ where $\mathbf x \in \Bbb R^n$, do you mean that the hypersurface lives in $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$ where $S \equiv x_{n + 1}$?

Comment: Yes, the surface $S$ lives in $R^{n+1}$ and $S=x_{n+1}$

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now must think . . . .

Comment: I think that there may be an issue defining the direction of the normal vector. Since I am interested only on the principal directions and the absolute values of the curvatures, I don't think the direction of the normal vector is important.

Comment: Well, if you reverse the sign of the normal, that will negate the shape operator, right?  which will negate all of it's eigenvalues but leave the eigendirections fixed.  If all you need are the abolute values of the eigenvalues, you should be fine.  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to find the shape operator for the hypersurface S in $R^n$